# How do you replace duplicate values with multiple unique strings in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Tom', 'Jack', 'Terry'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Lets say I have a dataframe that looks like this. I am trying to figure out how to check the Name column for the value 'Tom' and if I find it the first time I replace it with the value 'FirstTom' and the second time it appears I replace it with the value 'SecondTom'. How do you accomplish this? I've used the replace method before but only for replacing all Toms with a single value. I don't want to add a 1 on the end of the value, but completely change the string to something else.

Edit:

If the df looked more like this below, how would we check for Tom in the first column and the second column and then replace the first instance with FirstTom and the second instance with SecondTom

`data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Jerry', 'Jack', 'Terry'], 'OtherName':[Tom, John, Bob,Steve]}`

Answer (score 12):

Just adding in to the existing solutions , you can use [`inflect`](https://pypi.org/project/inflect/) to create dynamic dictionary

```
import inflect
p = inflect.engine()

df['Name'] += df.groupby('Name').cumcount().add(1).map(p.ordinal).radd('_')
print(df)
```

---

```
        Name  Age
0    Tom_1st   20
1    Tom_2nd   21
2   Jack_1st   19
3  Terry_1st   18
```

Comment: nice answer, while searching on google just found out this :)

Answer (score 10):

We can do `cumcount`

```
df.Name=df.Name+df.groupby('Name').cumcount().astype(str)
df
     Name  Age
0    Tom0   20
1    Tom1   21
2   Jack0   19
3  Terry0   18
```

Update

```
suf = lambda n: "%d%s"%(n,{1:"st",2:"nd",3:"rd"}.get(n if n<20 else n%10,"th"))
g=df.groupby('Name')


df.Name=df.Name.radd(g.cumcount().add(1).map(suf).mask(g.Name.transform('count')==1,''))
df
     Name  Age
0  1stTom   20
1  2ndTom   21
2    Jack   19
3   Terry   18
```

Update 2  for column

```
suf = lambda n: "%d%s"%(n,{1:"st",2:"nd",3:"rd"}.get(n if n<20 else n%10,"th"))

g=s.groupby([s.index.get_level_values(0),s])
s=s.radd(g.cumcount().add(1).map(suf).mask(g.transform('count')==1,''))
s=s.unstack()
     Name OtherName
0  1stTom    2ndTom
1   Jerry      John
2    Jack       Bob
3   Terry     Steve
```

Comment: OP need `I don't want to add a 1 on the end of the value`

Comment: This is great thank you. Now what if there is a second column of names and instead of checking the values vertically it checks for the same name horizontally?

Comment: @Logan0015L you can do df.groupby(['Name1','Name2']).cumcount()

Comment: @jezrael In my understanding, if we can not build the string 1st to....nth , I think it is better keep the number in the name

Comment: Could this be grouped by the row instead of the column?

Comment: @Logan0015 could you please show us more about your data ?

Comment: Hey YOBEN_S, Trying to understand your lambda code here.   suf = lambda n: "%d%s"%(n,{1:"st",2:"nd",3:"rd"}.get(n if n<20 else n%10,"th")) code.    I'm actually trying to implement it on the back side of the duplicate row value.  Example: 9996-1, 9996-2, 9996-3 and so on.  I can replace your "st", "nd" with a "-" but number and dash show on front of column string.   Can you help me understand this lambda so I can implement this .  Thanks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: For count duplicated per rows use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Jerry', 'Jack', 'Terry'], 
                          'OtherName':['Tom', 'John', 'Bob','Steve'],
                          'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]})

print (df)
    Name OtherName  Age
0    Tom       Tom   20
1  Jerry      John   21
2   Jack       Bob   19
3  Terry     Steve   18

import inflect
p = inflect.engine()

#map by function for dynamic counter
f = lambda i: p.number_to_words(p.ordinal(i))
#columns filled by names
cols = ['Name','OtherName']
#reshaped to MultiIndex Series
s = df[cols].stack()
#counter per groups
count = s.groupby([s.index.get_level_values(0),s]).cumcount().add(1)
#mask for filter duplicates
mask = s.reset_index().duplicated(['level_0',0], keep=False).values
#filter only duplicates and map, reshape back and add to original data
df[cols] = count[mask].map(f).unstack().add(df[cols], fill_value='')
print (df)
       Name  OtherName  Age
0  firstTom  secondTom   20
1     Jerry       John   21
2      Jack        Bob   19
3     Terry      Steve   18
```

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), but only for duplicated values by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Tom', 'Jack', 'Terry'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

nth = {
0: "First",
1: "Second",
2: "Third",
3: "Fourth"
}

mask = df.Name.duplicated(keep=False)
df.loc[mask, 'Name'] = df[mask].groupby('Name').cumcount().map(nth) + df.loc[mask, 'Name']
print (df)
        Name  Age
0   FirstTom   20
1  SecondTom   21
2       Jack   19
3      Terry   18
```

Dynamic dictionary should be like:

```
import inflect
p = inflect.engine()

mask = df.Name.duplicated(keep=False)
f = lambda i: p.number_to_words(p.ordinal(i))
df.loc[mask, 'Name'] = df[mask].groupby('Name').cumcount().add(1).map(f) + df.loc[mask, 'Name']
print (df)

        Name  Age
0   firstTom   20
1  secondTom   21
2       Jack   19
3      Terry   18
```

Comment: this is very slick use of map and cumcount, nice one. maybe add a step to show the number of possible cumulative counts and build up a dictionary dynamically?

Answer (score 6):

#### `transform`

```
nth = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth']

def prefix(d):
    n = len(d)
    if n > 1:
        return d.radd([nth[i] for i in range(n)])
    else:
        return d

df.assign(Name=df.groupby('Name').Name.transform(prefix))

          Name  Age
0     FirstTom   20
1    SecondTom   21
2         Jack   19
3        Terry   18
4   FirstSteve   17
5  SecondSteve   16
6   ThirdSteve   15
​
```